# gaussian naiive bayes with missing values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naive-bayes

I've got some data that I one-hot encode, A is numbers B is categories, C (the thing that I predict) is categories, so...

```
A | B | C
1 | a | cat
2 | b | dog
3 | c | apple
4 | a | dog
```

becomes

```
A | B_a | B_b |B_c | C_cat | C_dog | C_apple
1 | 1 | 0 | 0  | 1 | 0 | 0  
2 | 0 | 1 | 0  | 0 | 1 | 0
3 | 0 | 0 | 1  | 0 | 0 | 1
4 | 1 | 0 | 0  | 0 | 1 | 0
```

There are more categorical/numerical columns than I've shown

And now, I want to use gaussian NB to predict C.

Bascially `gnb.predict_proba([1,1,0,0])` would return something like `[99%,1%,1%]`

Where 1,1,0,0 means A = 1, and B is of category a.  Also that it's 99% likely to be a cat

I can get as far as fitting/predicting, but I can't figure out the "right" thing to do with missing data.

What if there's another column category, let's say D could be D_a, or D_b.

Should I do

```
P_A = gnb.predict_proba([1,1,0,0,0,0])
P_B = gnb.predict_proba([1,1,0,0,1,0])
P_C = gnb.predict_proba([1,1,0,0,0,1])
P_D = gnb.predict_proba([1,1,0,0,1,1])
```

Where the last two entries of each call correspond to D_a and D_b?  Since it's one-hot encoding do I only need to get P_B and P_C (since D_a and D_b are mutually exclusive)?

What do I do with these values once I get them?  Keep in mind, they're probabilities for C, so they're something like [99%,1%,1%]

Do I perform element-wise multiplication, or addition?